# Can't change viewcontroller from UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to modal to a view controller from a UIAlertView.

```
- (IBAction)cancelScripting:(id)sender {


UIAlertView *areYouSure = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Are You Sure?" message:@"Are you sure you want to quit scripting?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

[areYouSure show];



}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (buttonIndex == 1) {


    CRHViewController *firstView = [[CRHViewController alloc] init];


    [self.navigationController modalViewController:firstView animated:YES];    }
}
```

In my .h file I have a UINavigatoinDelegate set

```
@interface CRHScripting : UIViewController     <UITextViewDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

In storyboard I have my view controller's identifier set to firstView.

The line

```
[self.navigationController modalViewController:firstView animated:YES];
```

is giving me all the trouble.  The error says

```
"No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector     'modalViewController:animated:'
```

What does this mean?

**Update: Now My View wont't fully load, but it will show the view controller**

Here is my init code:

```
#import "CRHViewController.h"

@interface CRHViewController ()

@end

@implementation CRHViewController


-(void)updateTimer {

NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[format setDateFormat:@"h:mm"];
clockLabel.text = [format stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self     selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [homeIconScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [homeIconScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake (150,1100)];

    NSLog(@"Did Load first View"); 

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {



[UIImageView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:2];
[scrollNotify setAlpha:0];
[UIImageView commitAnimations];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion` is a UIViewController method not a UINavigationController method. The correct line is:

```
[self presentViewController:firstView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

*Note that `- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated` now shows as being deprecated. If you still want to use it:

```
[self presentModalViewController:firstView animated:YES];
```

Comment: that worked but when it modals to the view controller it comes up dark and I cant do anything.  Like it isn't enabled or something.

Comment: Is your new view controller loading successfully? Can you verify it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: its not loading successfully.

Comment: Strange. Could you add your init code for the `CRHViewController`? And maybe double check that it has a view attached.

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo: its `presentModalViewController`.

it throws that error because it can't find a method with that name you misspelled

Comment: It got rid of the error but now the button does nothing.  I put in an nslog and the button works, but it wont present the controller.

Comment: try using `didDismissWithButtonAtIndex` instead of `clickedButtonAtIndex`